# Подстановка параметра команды в bash

Tags: linux, bash, lame

Пишу скрипт для конвертирования flac в mp3 с преобразованием vorbis-комментариев в id3-теги. В $ARTIST содержится название исполнителя. В команду конвертирования нужно вставить этот тег только если он присутствует в исходном файле. Пытаюсь параметр команды --ta "$ARTIST":

```
if [ -z "$ARTIST" ]; then
    echo "ARTIST is empty"
    art=""; else
    art="--ta \"$ARTIST\""   #при использовании art="--ta $ARTIST" результат тот же
fi
```

вставить в команду: `flac -cd $name.flac | lame -$preset -q0 --id3v2-only --id3v2-utf16 -p $art $name.flac $preset/$name.mp3`

Результат: `lame: unrecognized option --ta "Track Artist"`

Хотя команда `flac -cd $name.flac | lame -$preset -q0 --id3v2-only --id3v2-utf16 -p --ta "$ARTIST" $name.flac $preset/$name.mp3` выполняется успешно.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему.

Comment: http://blog.buberel.org/batch-flac-to-ogg-convert.html - тут лежит ещё сорц flac2mp3. Может его заюзать, чем писать велосипеды?

Comment: @donRumata Насколько я понял, это слегка видоизмененный скрипт flac2ogg. Действительно, конвертирование из flac в mp3 простейшей командой, котрая используется в этом скрипте, - это велосипед, но, в данном случае, в mp3-файл не записываются теги, преобразованные из комментариев vorbis (что при конвертировании flac > ogg не требуется). При этом важно записывать в конечный файл только те теги, которые имеются в исходном.

Comment: попробуйте добавить команду `eval` перед именем программы `lame`: `flac ... | eval lame ...`

Comment: Да, ещё. Оно обязательно должно быть через скрипт или можно юзать гуй?

Comment: @donRumata Мне удобнее конвертировать через cli

Comment: Ок, но учти, что есть клёвая прога flacon. Я ей кучу флака в огг и мп3 нарезал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

работоспособный вариант — с использованием встроенной команды `eval`

```
str="word word"
arg="--ta '$str'"
eval lame $arg infile outfile
```

---

нерабочие варианты:

```
str="word word"
arg="--ta '$str'"
lame $arg infile outfile
```

ошибка:

> lame: excess arg outfile

и

```
str="word word"
arg="--ta '$str'"
lame "$arg" infile outfile
```

ошибка:

> lame: unrecognized option --ta 'word word'